help with table

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\label{table 1}
\begin{tabular}{ |l|c|c|c|c|c|l|c|c|c|c|c|@{\vphantom{$\bigg|$}}}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Forward Feed} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Backward Feed} \\
  \hline
  $$\#$$ & $$V_s(V)$$ & $$I(mA)$$ & $$V(V)$$ & $$\#$$ &   $$V_s (V)$$ & $$I (mA)$$ & $$V(V)$$ \\ 
  \hline
  $$1$$ & $$0.1$$ & $$0.0\pm0$$ & $$0.11\pm0.001$$ & $$1$$ & $$-0.1$$ & $$0$$ & $$-0.10\pm0.0008$$ \\
  \hline
  $$2$$ & $$0.2$$ & $$0.1\pm0.0012$$ & $$0.21\pm0.002$$ & $$2$$ & $$-0.2$$ & $$0$$ & $$-0.21 \pm0.002$$ \\ 
  \hline
  $$3$$ & $$0.3$$ & $$1.3\pm0.016$$ & $$0.3\pm0.002$$ & $$3$$ & $$-0.3$$ & $$0$$ & $$-0.32\pm0.003$$ \\
  \hline
  $$4$$ & $$0.4$$ & $$5.2\pm0.062$$ & $$0.35\pm0.003$$ & $$4$$ & $$-0.4$$ & $$0$$ & $$-0.42\pm0.003$$ \\
  \hline
  $$5$$ & $$0.5$$ & $$10.5\pm0.13$$ & $$0.38\pm0.003$$ & $$5$$ & $$-0.5$$ & $$0$$ & $$-0.53\pm0.004$$ \\
  \hline
  $$6$$ & $$0.6$$ & $$16.5\pm0.20$$ & $$0.4\pm0.003$$ & $$6$$ & $$-0.6$$ & $$0$$ & $$-0.62\pm0.005$$ \\
  \hline
  $$7$$ & $$0.7$$ & $$21.9\pm0.26$$ & $$0.42\pm0.003$$ & $$7$$ & $$-0.7$$ & $$0$$ & $$-0.73\pm0.006$$ \\ 
  \hline
  $$8$$ & $$0.8$$ & $$28.8\pm0.35$$ & $$0.44\pm0.004$$ & $$8$$ & $$-0.8$$ & $$0$$ & $$-0.83\pm0.007$$ \\
  \hline
  $$9$$ & $$0.9$$ & $$35.6\pm0.43$$ & $$0.45\pm0.004$$ & $$9$$ & $$-0.9$$ & $$0$$ & $$-0.94\pm0.008$$ \\
  \hline
  $$10$$ & $$1.0$$ & $$42.2\pm0.51$$ & $$0.046\pm0.004$$ & $$10$$ & $$-1.0$$ & $$0$$ & $$-1.04\pm0.008$$ \\
  \hline
  
\end{tabular} 

How can I make this table like the pic I included, bigger and wider? Mine looks so compact and small

Start by changing every $$ into $

Related/duplicate: Column and row padding in tables

Related: all of those $$ give you all sorts of errors.  You can't worry about how it looks until it compiles without error.

You might use siunitx:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{uncertainty-mode=separate}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
 |>{\vphantom{$\bigg|$}}r|
 S[table-format=1.1] |
 S[table-format=2.4(1)] |
 S[table-format=1.3(1)] |
 r|
 S[table-format=-1.1] |
 S[table-format=1.0] |
 S[table-format=-1.4(1)] |
}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|>{\vphantom{$\bigg|$}}c|}{Forward Feed} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Backward Feed} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|>{\vphantom{$\bigg|$}}c|}\# &
  {$V_s$ (\unit{V})} & 
  {$I$ (\unit{mA})} &
  {$V$ (\unit{V})} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}\# &
  {$V_s$ (\unit{V})} & 
  {$I$ (\unit{mA})} &
  {$V$ (\unit{V})} \\
\hline
1 & 0.1 & 0.0\pm0 & 0.11\pm0.001 & 1 & -0.1 & 0 & -0.10\pm0.0008 \\
\hline
2 & 0.2 & 0.1\pm0.0012 & 0.21\pm0.002 & 2 & -0.2 & 0 & -0.21 \pm0.002 \\ 
\hline
3 & 0.3 & 1.3\pm0.016 & 0.3\pm0.002 & 3 & -0.3 & 0 & -0.32\pm0.003 \\
\hline
4 & 0.4 & 5.2\pm0.062 & 0.35\pm0.003 & 4 & -0.4 & 0 & -0.42\pm0.003 \\
\hline
5 & 0.5 & 10.5\pm0.13 & 0.38\pm0.003 & 5 & -0.5 & 0 & -0.53\pm0.004 \\
\hline
6 & 0.6 & 16.5\pm0.20 & 0.4\pm0.003 & 6 & -0.6 & 0 & -0.62\pm0.005 \\
\hline
7 & 0.7 & 21.9\pm0.26 & 0.42\pm0.003 & 7 & -0.7 & 0 & -0.73\pm0.006 \\ 
\hline
8 & 0.8 & 28.8\pm0.35 & 0.44\pm0.004 & 8 & -0.8 & 0 & -0.83\pm0.007 \\
\hline
9 & 0.9 & 35.6\pm0.43 & 0.45\pm0.004 & 9 & -0.9 & 0 & -0.94\pm0.008 \\
\hline
10 & 1.0 & 42.2\pm0.51 & 0.046\pm0.004 & 10 & -1.0 & 0 & -1.04\pm0.008 \\
\hline
  
\end{tabular} 

\end{table}

\end{document}


However, I propose a different look.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\sisetup{uncertainty-mode=separate}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
 @{}
 r
 S[table-format=1.1]
 S[table-format=2.4(1)]
 S[table-format=1.3(1)]
 S[table-format=-1.1]
 S[table-format=1.0]
 S[table-format=-1.4(1)]
 @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{\#} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Forward Feed} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Backward Feed} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
& {$V_s$ (\unit{V})} & 
  {$I$ (\unit{mA})} &
  {$V$ (\unit{V})} &
  {$V_s$ (\unit{V})} & 
  {$I$ (\unit{mA})} &
  {$V$ (\unit{V})} \\
\midrule
 1 & 0.1 & 0.0\pm0 & 0.11\pm0.001 & -0.1 & 0 & -0.10\pm0.0008 \\
 2 & 0.2 & 0.1\pm0.0012 & 0.21\pm0.002 & -0.2 & 0 & -0.21 \pm0.002 \\ 
 3 & 0.3 & 1.3\pm0.016 & 0.3\pm0.002 & -0.3 & 0 & -0.32\pm0.003 \\
 4 & 0.4 & 5.2\pm0.062 & 0.35\pm0.003 & -0.4 & 0 & -0.42\pm0.003 \\
 5 & 0.5 & 10.5\pm0.13 & 0.38\pm0.003 & -0.5 & 0 & -0.53\pm0.004 \\
 6 & 0.6 & 16.5\pm0.20 & 0.4\pm0.003 & -0.6 & 0 & -0.62\pm0.005 \\
 7 & 0.7 & 21.9\pm0.26 & 0.42\pm0.003 & -0.7 & 0 & -0.73\pm0.006 \\ 
 8 & 0.8 & 28.8\pm0.35 & 0.44\pm0.004 & -0.8 & 0 & -0.83\pm0.007 \\
 9 & 0.9 & 35.6\pm0.43 & 0.45\pm0.004 & -0.9 & 0 & -0.94\pm0.008 \\
10 & 1.0 & 42.2\pm0.51 & 0.046\pm0.004 & -1.0 & 0 & -1.04\pm0.008 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 

\end{table}

\end{document}


